# Bootstrap based desing PHP form saved on changing value on second time

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to save PHP form made using bootstrap. I am getting value for select field(Program) from database. Depending on that I am getting value of schedule. When I am submitting the form it is not submitted at first time. When I again select program value it get saved.

My PHP code is as follows :-

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" id="registerForm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                                      </div>
                                 </div>
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                                  </div>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Mobile</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber">
                                      </div>
                                 </div>

                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Enquiry Date</label>
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="enquiry_date" id="enquiry_date">
                                      </div>
                                 </div>


                             </div>
                              <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Program </label>
                                         <select class="form-control margin-bottom-20"  name="program" id="program">
                                        <option value="">Select Program</option>
                                        <?php
                                        $query = "SELECT * FROM programme";

                                        $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

                                        while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                            echo "<option value='";
                                            echo $record['program_name'];
                                            echo "'>";
                                            echo $record['program_name'];
                                            echo "</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                      </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Schedule</label>
                                    <select class="form-control margin-bottom-20"  name="date" id="date">
                                        <?php include 'get_sch.php'; ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                 </div>

                             </div>
                             <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Shift </label>
                                        <select class="form-control margin-bottom-20"  name="shift" id="shift">
                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="morning">Morning</option>
                                        <option value="evening">Evening</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                 </div>

                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Remark </label>
                                        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" name="remark">
                                      </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <hr>

                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">Enquire</button>
                            </form>
```

Inserting sql code is

```
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO `enquiry` (`mobile`, `name`, `email`, `enquiry_date`, `program_name`, `schedule`, `shift`, `remark`, `user_login`) VALUES ('$mobile','$name','$email','$enquiry_date','$program', '$schedule','$shift', '$remark','$login')";
```

Comment: That's all you have?

Comment: use `var_dump($_POST)` and check what you get when you hit the save button first time

Comment: It is returning nothing.